# Loading Django template tag libraries using dotted notation

Tags: django, django-templates

The template tags for an built using Django 1.1 organized within modules, like `some_tags.py` below:

```
myproject
|__  __init__.py
|__  manage.py
|__  settings.py
|__  myapp
     |__  __init__.py
     |__  admin.py
     |__  models.py
     |__  templates
     |__  templatetags
          |__  __init__.py
          |__  group1
          |__  group2
              |__  __init__.py
              |__  some_tags.py
     |__  views.py
|__  templates
|__  urls.py
```

And then to load those tags I could use `{load group1.some_tags %}`. After porting the project to Django 1.2.5, those templates are generating errors (which are neatly solved by removing this load line). The module itself imports just fine from the shell, which is not the case when there's an error in the code.

The errors are:

```
ImportError: No module named group1
```

and

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named group1
```

**Was support for dotted notation like this loading template tag libraries removed?** I haven't seen anything in the release notes that would suggest this.

If this notation is no longer supported, what's a better alternative to organizing the template tag libraries without placing them all at the same file level?

Comment: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.5/django/template/defaulttags.py#L911 Looks like dotted modules are supported. Is "myapp" in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes - everything else works - the project runs fine as is on Django 1.1

Comment: doesn't /myapp/templatetags/ need to have an `__init__.py` as well?

Comment: Going off on a tangent, in 1.3 (released today) you can do `{% load some_tags from group1 %}`

Comment: @kb - yes, present in the code, was missing above (oversimplified). @StephenPaulger - off tangent indeed, but helpful to know!

Comment: If it was simply a matter of not being able to find the templatetag library, the `import_library` called by `load` catches `ImportError` and would raise `InvalidTemplateLibrary`.  I think the templatetag library is found and being loaded properly, but that ImportError comes later.